# Changing the color of the angular material checkbox checkmark

Tags: angular

I've been having a really hard time finding a solution that makes the color of the checkmark in the angular material checkbox the color white. I tried changing between themes and have gone through all stack posts, but nothing seems to work. How can I get the checkmark to turn white?

`<mat-checkbox class="buyItNowLabel" [(ngModel)]="buyItNowEnabled">Buy It Now Only</mat-checkbox>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think something like this

in component.css

```
::ng-deep mat-checkbox.buyItNowLabel .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: red !important;
}
```

in styles.css

```
mat-checkbox.buyItNowLabel .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: red !important;
}
```

if you want to replace color for all of the checkbox you can change the selector to

in component.css

```
::ng-deep mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: red !important;
}
```

in styles.css

```
mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: #fa3131;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #fa3131 !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate .mat-checkbox-background {
    border-color: #ff6f00 !important;
    background-color: #ff6f00 !important;
}

::ng-deep mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: white !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can use below CSS:

```
::ng-deep mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke: {color} !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your color like this in your html tag

```
color="primary"
```

In your tag

```
<mat-checkbox color="primary" class="buyItNowLabel" [(ngModel)]="buyItNowEnabled">Buy It Now Only</mat-checkbox>
```

You can see more about it, [here](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples#checkbox-overview)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR ANGULAR 15**

It was really hard for me to find a relevant answer concerning Angular 15 as components changed due to the "mdc" class introduction.

I found a solution which works for Angular 15 and wanted to share it here.

**HTML** looks something like this

```
 <div class="mdc-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control">
   <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
      <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark">
        <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path"></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS** has to access the path-attribute

```
    // Checkmark color
.mdc-checkbox__native-control:checked~.mdc-checkbox__background 
.mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on angular material 15+ (not legacy) you can change colors by changing css variables

here is example changing the stroke and the box it self to white color
this is in the `styles.scss` file

```
.mdc-checkbox {
    --mdc-checkbox-selected-checkmark-color: #fff;
    --mdc-checkbox-unselected-icon-color: #fff;
    --mdc-checkbox-unselected-pressed-icon-color: #fff;
    --mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-icon-color: #fff;
    --mdc-checkbox-unselected-focus-icon-color: #fff;
}
```

at least all the variables has names so you  can read what you want to change.